# .ajax not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i am trying  to make an ajax request it is not working properly

my code

```
function checkUserName() {
        debugger
        var userName = 'vipin jain';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/isUserAvailable",
            data: { userName: "+userName+" },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
                $(".successNotification").removeAttr('display');
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

can u tell me what is going wrong.

Comment: Explain how it is not working properly?

Comment: can you explain what is not working ?

Comment: Do you send jSon formatted object or just an object?

Comment: btw, Default.aspx/isUserAvailable is a broken url.. maybe you ment default.aspx

Comment: also, `data: { userName: "+userName+" },` or do you mean to use `data: { userName: userName },`

Comment: If this is a WCF service and not ASPX page then you should allow JSON requests like     [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should notice what is going wrong, what error message you are receiving, what doesn't work as expected. From this I can see 2 possible things going wrong:

The `debugger` line, what is that about? Remove it and debug with Firebug in Firefox

`data: { userName: "+userName+" },` This always gives '+userName+' as the username, I guess you need the username here? Do it like this: `{ userName: userName }`.

Comment: thank you for the reponse i got the culprit   data:" { userName: '"+ userName +"' }",  i correct this and worked perfectly.